# How to use curl PHP in loop with 100 time?

Tags: php, arrays, curl

How to use curl in loop 100 times with send request and store response in an array?

For example : when curl uses in loop first time and gets 500 records and store in an array and again the same process with the second loop and gets 500 records form response  and store in the same array without any issues. Finally, I need store 50K records in the array and I will use for insert records in my database.

I am working last 2 days but not getting any solution for this so please help me.

```
<?php
$final_data = array();
for($d=1;$d<=100;$d++)
{   
    $data = '{"request": {"header": {"username": "xxx","password": "xxx"},
    "body": {
    "shapes": [],
    "size_to": "",
    "size_from": "",
    "color_from": "",
    "color_to": "",
    "clarity_from": "",
    "clarity_to": "",
    "cut_from": "",
    "cut_to": "",
    "polish_from": "",
    "polish_to": "",
    "symmetry_from": "",
    "symmetry_to": "",
    "labs": [],
    "price_total_from": "",
    "price_total_to": "",
    "page_number": "1",
    "page_size": "50",
    "sort_by": "price",
    "sort_direction": "ASC"
    }}}';

    $json = json_decode($data,true);
    $json['request']['body']['page_number'] = $d;
    $data = json_encode($json); 

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://technet.rapaport.com/HTTP/JSON/RetailFeed/GetDiamonds.aspx');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    $dd = json_decode($result,true);

    foreach($dd['response']['body']['diamonds'] as $key)
    {       
        array_push($final_data,$key);
    }   
    curl_close($curl);
}
?>
```

Comment: How does the browser crashing have anything to do with your server-side code? You also need to give a lot more details, code etc for anyone to understand what you're doing.

Comment: How long does this take? A browser isn't made to wait minutes until the completion of a serverside process. The client quite possibly just sees "Oops, time out" or something like this.

Comment: sorry for my invalid question i already updated my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [curl_multi](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php), it is more efficient when having several requests to perform.

```
$mh = curl_multi_init();
$handles = array();

for($i = 0 ; $i < 100 ; $i++){
    $ch = curl_init();
    $handles[] = $ch;

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://technet.rapaport.com/HTTP/JSON/RetailFeed/GetDiamonds.aspx');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh,$ch);
}

$running = null;
do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
} while ($running);

foreach($handles as $ch){
    $result = curl_multi_getcontent($ch);

    $dd = json_decode($result,true);

    foreach($dd['response']['body']['diamonds'] as $key){       
        array_push($final_data,$key);
    }   

    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: Mind blowing solution @vincenth. Thank you very much.
I have no reputation score so I am not able to give you the rating.

Comment: It does not matter, as long as it helped you.

Comment: Thank you @vincenth

Comment: Saved my day! Thank you for this solution.