# Open URLs from mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a table at MySQL database and I insert at it just URLs.
So when I run this query:

```
SELECT postback_url 
FROM voluum 
LIMIT 20;
```

I get the result at this screenshot:
[image]

All I need right now is to make MySQL opens the URL every time I insert new row.
Those URLs are postback URLs and we receive them from third party tool so we don't have the option to fire those Postbacks from their side before they send it.
All we do right now just download those URLs and open them manually.
Is there any way to open any new record the third party tool sends us from Mysql automatically?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how to do this from MySQL, but it would be fairly straightforward to write a simple app + UI which can do this.

Comment: I don't think MySQL can 'open' the URLs. What you need to do is create a simple script in whatever language you're comfortable with that loops through `postback_url`, and for each URL, opens the web browser with that URL. But I'm guessing the URL expects a GET request, so you don't actually need to open the web browser, just send a GET request to each of the URL.

Comment: Natively, no mysql does not support such functionality. You can create (or use) compiled user defined functions to achieve such functionality within mysql, but I would go down the application route. Will be so much easier!

Answer (score 0):

It can not be done with MySQL directly.

You can use PHP to

1. read the MySQL and extract the URLs you need to open.
2. open the URLs: you can use curl_multi to perform all the URL calls

See an example in the reply from @vincenth here about curl_multi:
[How to use curl PHP in loop with 100 time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38967821/how-to-use-curl-php-in-loop-with-100-time)

Answer (score -1):

This php code should work, or will need a little brush up but note it will open 20 tabs since you have 20 results...

```
<?php 
echo '<script>'
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM voluum LIMIT 20" ;
  $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
  $results = mysqli_fetch_all($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  foreach (results as result){
   echo 'window.open("'.$result['postback_url'].'" );':
 }
 echo '</script>'
?>
```